# Why does sys.getsizeof() not return [size] in file.read([size]) in Python

Tags: python, string, file-io

I have a large binary file that I would like to read in and unpack using struct.unpack()
The file consists of a number of lines each 2957 bytes long. 
I read in the file using the following code:

```
with open("bin_file", "rb") as f:
    line = f.read(2957)
```

My question is why, is the size returned by:

```
import sys
sys.getsizeof(line)
```

not equal to 2957 (in my case it is 2978)?

Comment: What are you using `sys.getsizeof` for?

Comment: @hobbs I am not using it for anything in particular, I just noticed the discrepancy and was wondering why that is the case

Comment: All this has nothing to do with file I/O; you'd get the same result with `line = ' ' * 2957`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You misunderstand what `sys.getsizeof()` *does*. It returns the amount of memory Python uses for a string object, not length of the line.

Python string objects track reference counts, the object type and other metadata together with the actual characters, so 2978 bytes is *not* the same thing as the string length.

See the [`stringobject.h` definition of the type](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3f13f1620d70/Include/stringobject.h#l35):

```c
typedef struct {
    PyObject_VAR_HEAD
    long ob_shash;
    int ob_sstate;
    char ob_sval[1];

    /* Invariants:
     *     ob_sval contains space for 'ob_size+1' elements.
     *     ob_sval[ob_size] == 0.
     *     ob_shash is the hash of the string or -1 if not computed yet.
     *     ob_sstate != 0 iff the string object is in stringobject.c's
     *       'interned' dictionary; in this case the two references
     *       from 'interned' to this object are *not counted* in ob_refcnt.
     */
} PyStringObject;
```

where `PyObject_VAR_HEAD` is defined in [`object.h`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3f13f1620d70/Include/object.h#l77), where the standard `ob_refcnt`, `ob_type` and `ob_size` fields are all defined.

So a string of length 2957 takes 2958 bytes (string length + null) and the remaining 20 bytes you see are to hold the reference count, the type pointer, the object 'size' (string length here), the cached string hash and the interned state flag.

Other object types will have different memory footprints, and the exact sizes of the C types used differ from platform to platform as well.

Answer (score 3):

A string object representing 2957 bytes of data takes more than 2957 bytes of memory to represent, due to overhead such as the type pointer and the reference count. `sys.getsizeof` includes this additional overhead.